# Quais são as diferenças entre Java SE, Java EE e Java ME?

Tags: java

Estou estudando a Linguagem Java no curso de Sistemas de informação e percebi que a linguagem java está contida em nosso dia dia mesmo sem percebermos. Ela está presente tanto nos nossos computadores quanto em nosso telefones moveis e em nossas tvs.

Sei que a Plataforma Java se divide em três principais Ambientes de desenvolvimento **Java SE**, **Java EE** e **Java ME**, então gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os ambientes?

Comment: Nesse link cita algumas diferenças: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html

Comment: Java ME está morto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36677231/540552

Answer (score 16):

## Java SE = Standard Edition

Contém os recursos básicos (java.lang, java.io, java.math, java.net, java.util, etc...). É normalmente por onde deve-se começar o aprendizado.

## Java EE = Enterprise Edition

É indicado para um uso mais robusto. Aplicações de larga escala, sistemas distribuídos, etc. Possui os recursos básicos (JAVA SE), obviamente, e recursos extras como bibliotecas para acesso a bancos de dados (JDBC, JPA), APIs diversas (JMS, RMI), Java Server Pages, servlets, portlets, etc.

## Java ME = Micro Edition

Indicado para dispositivos mobile e sistemas embutidos. Essa edição é baseada numa antiga versão do JAVA SE.

Comment: Java ME pode ser considerado obsoleto?

Comment: @epx em comparação com o que se tem hoje em dia tanto para mobile quanto para embarcados, sem sombra de dúvidas